# ldaseqmodel runtimewarning Invalid value in double_scalars

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda

I am currently trying to use dynamic topic modeling on some news crawled from the web.
Unfortunately, I receive a warning in the logs:

INFO : using serial LDA version on this node

```
path/to/gensim/models/ldaseqmodel.py:1472: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars converged = np.fabs((lhood_old - lhood) / (lhood_old * total))
```

After using google to find out more about this issue, I learned that this numpy error is often produced by NaNs or null values. So with regards to dynamic topic modeling this probably refers to an empty document? but I dont have any empty documents in my dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Because of the lack of reputation, I am unable to comment which is why I am writing my suggestion here. So you may have done some pre-processing before running the `ldaseqmodel` of `gensim`. First, check that after all the pre-processing you have done is there any empty document in your corpus. To check that if it is in the list of lists format(generally it is in the list of lists format) you can do this:

```
for i in range(len(bow_corpus)): #bow_corpus is the corpus
    if len(bow_corpus[i])==0: #check for empty document
        print(i) #if there is any empty document then print the index of that document
```

By running the above you will get all the indices of the empty documents. Then you can simply remove the corresponding documents.